# Após reverter um merge de um repo para o fork, o git não permite fazer outro (already up-to-date)

Tags: git, github

Boas galera!

Tenho pouca experiência com GIT (por isso, trabalho principalmente com o Github Desktop mais do que com a linha de comando), e hoje tive alguns problemas com um fork do repositório de um tema phpbb que eu venho trabalhando.

O primeiro deles na verdade começou há uns 16 dias. Tive dúvidas específicas de desenvolvimento do estilo e precisava compartilhar o código do repositório aqui no stack. O problema é que o fork é privado, presumo que seja pelo fato do repositório original também ser (já que eu não tenho conta premium no github). Então eu tentei duplicar o repositório em outro público, [conforme esse tutorial do próprio site](https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository/).
Porém eu não prestei atenção que após realizar esse procedimento os meus commits estavam indo parar no repositorio-clone, e não mais no original (o fork privado).
Eu só fui notar isso hoje, quando tentei fazer fazer um update to repositório pai para o fork (via github desktop) e ele não processava a ação. Depois de procurar vários tutoriais na internet eu acessei ambos os repositórios via web e notei a ausência de commits depois dessa data no fork e todos os meus commits no repo clone, incluindo o merge que o github desktop acusou como falho.

Consegui resolver esse problema repetindo o tutorial acima só que com os repositorios "invertidos": copiei do clone para o fork. Aparentemente o problema estava resolvido.

Eu então recomeçei a desenvolver e percebi que esse merge embaralhou várias coisas na estrutura do código, e percebi que precisaria reverter esse merge. Aí é que começou o pior problema (e o principal dessa pergunta).

Inicialmente tentei pelo Github Desktop, que exigiu que eu o fizesse via linha de comando (a explicação que eu encontrei foi pois esse tipo de merge tem 2 commits parent, e eu precisava referenciar qual eu queria reverter, no caso o último commit da minha fork) usando `git revert -m`. Aparentemente ele conseguiu reverter.

Porém, após conseguir reverter esse merge via esse tutorial, o github agora me insiste em dizer que o fork está atualizado com o repo original (tanto na linha de comando quanto no Github GUI), e com isso eu não consigo trazer as mudanças de novo do repo pai para o fork, para resolver corretamente os conflitos.

Esse é um comportamento normal do GIT/Github, é um bug e o principal: é possível sincronizar novamente ou seria necessário esperar um commit novo lá do repo pai, e se for necessário isso, ele vai pegar TODAS as diferenças de 16 dias pra cá ou vai pegar só as commits criadas depois da minha tentativa fracassada de merge?

Segue a imagem da network pelo site do github, a seta vermelha que eu coloquei aonde a linha azul (que representa o repo original) juntando-se à linha preta (meu fork) é o merge que eu dei e depois reverti (o próximo ponto após essa junção). Os pontos à frente destes são commits que eu tentei dar pra forçar um update, sem sucesso.
[image: network]

Um forte abraço a todos!

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema.

Tive que dar, na linha de comando, um `git reset --hard <ultima commit antes do merge>` e logo depois um `git push --force` para forçar a alteração no servidor.